# Codeigniter - Rewrite to subdirectory containing wordpress installation in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have CodeIgniter at localhost/site and Wordpress in a subdirectory at localhost/site/blog.

Each is working fine - except I want certain urls in the site directory to point to the Wordpress subdirectory.

I'm forwarding them in the site folder's .htaccess like so (I'm a rewrite noob):

```
RewriteEngine On

RedirectMatch Permanent ^/site/about/? /site/blog/about

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond $1 !(^site/blog/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

The problem is that `localhost/site/about/` always forwards to 
`localhost/site/blog/about/` and changes the address bar.  I need the page at `localhost/site/blog/about/` to be served up when a user visits `localhost/site/about`.

In order to view the page at `localhost/site/blog/about/`, I had to add the RewriteBase directive and alter the RewriteRule in the following .htaccess in the blog subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site/blog/index.php [L]
```

Without this addition, the page at `localhost/site/blog/about` shows the CodeIgniter 404 error page.  (The RewriteBase actually seems to have no effect).

Eventually, the site will be hosted at www.site.com and the Wordpress installation will be at www.site.com/blog.

I've tried a bunch of different solutions and nothing has worked.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `site/about/` always forwards to `site/blog/about/` is because you have told it to with: `RedirectMatch Permanent ^/site/about/? /site/blog/about`
To have `site/about/` stay in the URL bar, but show the content from `site/blog/about/` the following should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site/about/$ /site/blog/about/ [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  With the RewriteRule above, the CodeIgniter 404 error page displays at site/about/.